# eval always returns error when executing a function having a return statement

Tags: javascript, eval

This block of code always returns errors:

```
eval('if(!var_a){return 0;}');
```

A statement like this works perfectly fine:

```
eval('alert(1)');
```

A JavaScript statement such as `eval('return 0')` always gives an error when its intention is to make the script stop further execution.

`eval` simply gives unwanted errors when it is run in some block of code and a return statement is in it.

Comment: The easy solution is to stop using `eval()`.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are using return outside of the context of a function. Wrap your code in a function and return works fine. There are a few ways to do that. **I suggest that you *do not* use any of them**. Instead find a way to avoid eval. Regardless, here are some solutions:

`eval('(function() { if(!var_a){return 0;} })()');`

or

`new Function('if(!var_a){return 0;}')()`

Comment: +1 for both answering the question and warning against using the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can only `return` from within a function. Like so:

```
function foo() {
    if (x) alert("woo");
    else return 0;
    doMoreStuff();
 }
```

You're not in a function, so there's nothing to return from. Also, why are you using `eval` at all?

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you are attempting to execute an expression with a `return`. In the second case, you are calling a function that returns a value. To do what you want, you can declare and invoke an anonymous function within the expression as follows...

```
eval('(function(){ if(!var_a){return 0;} })()');
```

Of course, if the question is just how to construct an evaluateable expression that includes a condition, you can use the "ternary" operator...

```
eval('var_a ? nil : 0');
```