# 'return' statement outside of function in IE 10 and IE 11

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I have a following asp control

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" onclick="return validate();"
                            runat="server" Text="submit" CssClass="next" />
```

and below is the js function Validate

```
function Validate()
{if (some condition){return true} else return false;  }
```

this code is working fine in all the browsers other than IE10 and IE11
the function is always returning a value. But when I debugged in IE11 or in 10, I am getting issue
" 'return' statement outside of function" after function executes.

What could be the actual cause?

well, I am editing this question as I just came to know that the issue is something else.
I was using complete statement 'return Validate()' in Add Watch of IE to see the real value and was getting the error 'return' statement outside of function". When I tried same with only 'Validate()' I got 'true' as its value. Function is returning proper value true or false based on condition, but the actual issue I am getting in IE10 or IE11 is that even after getting true as return value of Validate function my form is not submitted to server.
Any Idea ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I get this error! \[ 'return' statement outside of function \]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168713/i-get-this-error-return-statement-outside-of-function)

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code as it looks in the browser via "view source". In plain HTML, the value of event handler attributes is *always* implicitly wrapped in a function body.

Comment: You might be going down the wrong path by focussing on the 'if else'.  It might be the condition that's the true cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case no need to have the `else part` in you code.

```
function Validate() {
     if (some condition) {
        return true;
     } 
     return false;  
}
```

Also Terminate the line `return true` by adding the `;`.

**Or**

The shorthand way is

```
 function Validate() { 
     return ((some condition) ? true : false); 
 }
```

Thanks to [@pholpar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704022/pholpar) for the suggestion.

Comment: Would not be it enough to use function Validate() { return (some condition) } ??

Comment: @pholpar I think, if suppose the function doesn't return anything when condition is not met. The function would be returning `undefined` isn't? To avoid that we need to have `return false;` statement in the function.

Comment: My function consists only a single return statement (there is no if block at all), so as long (some condition) evaluates to a boolean value (as it should, since it is used in an if block in the original version), there is no way to return something that you can not interpret as a boolean. If (some condition) would be undefined, it will be interpreted as a false boolean value.

Comment: If you really want to return true or false explicitly, even if 'some condition' would be an undefined expression, you can use this version: function Validate() { return ((some condition) ? true : false); }

Comment: @pholpar Thank u, i completely forgot this when i was answering, i will update this as Short hand way (Edit).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused by not using an anonymous method in your onclick handler, like:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" onclick="function(){return validate();};"runat="server" Text="submit" CssClass="next" />
```

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3168756/704022), or [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8689855/704022).

Furthermore, you could simplify your `Validate` method as:

```
function Validate() { 
  return (some condition);
 }
```